# Youtube thumbnail api

Tags: gdata-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to retrieve thumbnail videos from youtube by calling the youtube api (gdata) using java? 
Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 2):

YouTube-videos have 4 thumbnails, that are accessible by a specific URL:

```
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/default.jpg  
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/1.jpg  
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/2.jpg  
http://i.ytimg.com/vi/VIDEO_ID/3.jpg
```

So just by knowing the video ID you can get the thumbnails just like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a read on "Video entry contents" section in the below link

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java